# Dmidecode --type 17 error information handling

Tags: dmidecode

Am getting the error information handle value in a hexadecimal format and it gives value as 0x0000.
What does **Error Information Handle:0x0000** mean in the memory information ?

```
# dmidecode 3.2
#Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
#SMBIOS 2.7 present.

Handle 0x1000, DMI type 16, 19 bytes
Physical Memory Array
        Location: Other
        Use: System Memory
        Error Correction Type: Multi-bit ECC
        Maximum Capacity: 32 GB
        Error Information Handle: Not Provided
        Number Of Devices: 2

Handle 0x1100, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x1000
        Error Information Handle: 0x0000
        Total Width: 64 bits
        Data Width: 64 bits
        Size: 16384 MB
        Form Factor: DIMM
        Set: None
        Locator: DIMM 0
        Bank Locator: Not Specified
        Type: RAM
        Type Detail: None
        Speed: Unknown
        Manufacturer: Not Specified
        Serial Number: Not Specified
        Asset Tag: Not Specified
        Part Number: Not Specified
        Rank: Unknown
        Configured Memory Speed: Unknown

Handle 0x1101, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x1000
        Error Information Handle: 0x0000
        Total Width: 64 bits
        Data Width: 64 bits
        Size: 16384 MB
        Form Factor: DIMM
        Set: None
        Locator: DIMM 1
        Bank Locator: Not Specified
        Type: RAM
        Type Detail: None
        Speed: Unknown
        Manufacturer: Not Specified
        Serial Number: Not Specified
        Asset Tag: Not Specified
        Part Number: Not Specified
        Rank: Unknown
        Configured Memory Speed: Unknown
```

Answer (score 2):

For reference, the [DMI specification](https://www.dmtf.org/sites/default/files/standards/documents/DSP0134_3.0.0.pdf) is the best place to look for the DMI field explanation.  You need to refer to section 7.18 "Memory Device".

DMI type 17 (Memory Device (Type 17) structure) structure bytes 0x06..0x07 provide a 16 bit value called the "Memory Error Information Handle."  If the system does not provide the error information structure, the field contains hex value 0xfffe; otherwise, the field contains 0xffff or the handle of the error info structure.

The handle refers to the Handle number as provided by DMI table type 18 ("32-Bit Error Information) in bytes 0x02..0x03 in this table. Section 7.19 of the DMI specification describes this structure.  In your case, you need to look at the full DMI dump and look for tables with DMI type 18 and check for the one that has the matching handle number 0x0000.  This has fields that describe the memory error type (See section 7.19.1 for the error types), the memory operation that caused the error and even the 32 bit physical address of the error (if you are lucky).

Comment: But the code in there necessarily means that there is one error, or can it mean anything else?

Comment: For that DMI specific code, I'm not sure.